# read_private_pages capability not working for new role

Tags: user-roles, private

I have created a new user role - *vendor* - with the capability to `read_private_pages`, but when I log in as such a user, and go to a private page I cannot see it.

Here is my plugin code:

```
function fc_add_role($role, $display_name, $capabilities = array()) {
    if (!empty($role)) {
        return wp_roles()->add_role( $role, $display_name, $capabilities );
    }
}
if (!get_role('vendor')){
    fc_add_role('vendor', 'Vendor', array('read_private_pages', 'read_private_posts'));
}
```

And when I go to my private page as a vendor, it just shows:

> **Oops! That page can’t be found.**
>
> It looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try one of the
>   links below or a search?

What am I doing wrong? And how can I make it so vendor users can read private pages?

NB - When I log in as admin, I can see the private page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your capabilities should be a key value pair:

```
fc_add_role('vendor', 'Vendor', array(
        'read_private_pages' => true, 
        'read_private_posts' => true
    ));
```